# Temporary ArrayList Replacement

Tags: java

I'm setting a temporary ArrayList equal to a pre-established ArrayList. Changes to the temporary ArrayList seem to also transfer over to the pre-established one. Why does this occur and how can I keep the pre-established ArrayList unchanged?

I know that this phenomenon does not occur in situations that involve ints.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    array.add(i);
}

ArrayList<Integer> tempArr = array;
tempArr.remove(0);
```

I expect array to be [0,1,2], but I get [1,2]. I would like the output to be array = [0,1,2] and tempArr = [1,2].

Answer (score 0):

You just copied the reference of the list to the new variable. That means you have 2 references `array` and `tempArr` that are pointing to the same object. You could create a new `ArrayList` from the old one:

```
ArrayList<Integer> tempArr = new ArrayList<>(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables `array` and `tempArr` booth point to same instance of `ArrayList<Integer>` object, hence modifying one will make changes to other.

What you need is to create new instance and then transfer all elements to it:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    array.add(i);
}

ArrayList<Integer> tempArr = new Arraylist<>();
tempArr.addAll(array);
tempArr.remove(0);
```

This code can also be simplified since Arraylist<> is offering you constructor that will add elements from another collection:

```
ArrayList<Integer> tempArr = new Arraylist<>(array);
tempArr.remove(0);
```